# JDK1.8 in Production but JDK 1.7 in Testing Environment

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, java-7, production-environment

What will Happen If I have  JDK 1.8 in my Production Environment but on Testing Environment JDK 1.7 ?

Comment: Then you'll have different versions on both environments, I guess. But jokes aside - the question is quite broad. You will have to maintain you code compilant with java 7, so you won't be able to use java 8 api, only some features of the jvm (garbage collectors etc.). On the other hand setting up your jvm differently would cause performance problem, that you won't be able to reproduce. Test environment should resemble production as much as possible.

Comment: What is *already* happening is that every second of time and every cent of money you are putting into testing this way is completely wasted. You have to test in the same environment as production. Otherwise you aren't testing at all.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have any significant issues between Java 1.7 for testing and Java 1.8 for production. Problems exist beyond the 1.9 transition, but 1.7 and 1.8 are compatible.

What you might find is that combinations of start-up flags for the JVM itself (which GC you're using, any additional flags) are different between the two versions. So if you're using a start-up script to set `JAVA_OPTIONS` then there may be differences in the way that they are launched.

Finally, if you're doing any kind of performance testing then the tests won't be valid between the two JVMs. Even if you're using the same GC configuration, the performance differences in Java 1.7 are likely to be slightly different from Java 1.8.